# how to highlight all occurrences of a word in vim on double clicking

Tags: vim, highlighting

When I'm on Windows, I use notepad++, and on Linux I use vim. I really like vim. But there is at least one thing I find really interesting in notepad++. You can double-click on a word and it highlights all occurrences of that word automatically. I was wondering if I could do something like that with vim? So the question is how to highlight all occurrences of a word when you double click on the word in vim.

Obviously, I **don't want to search** for that word, or change my cursor position, just highlighting. My `:set hlsearch` is also on.

probably you may want to avoid the mouse in vim, but I make an exception here :).

I know that `*` does the same job, but what about mouse?

Comment: `*` will move cursor to next occurrence of the word.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can map * to double-click by a simple mapping:

```
:map <2-LeftMouse> *
```

If you want to use said functionality in insert-mode you can use this mapping:

```
:imap <2-LeftMouse> <c-o>*
```

Without  (Ctrl-o) the * would be printed

**[EDIT]**
As ZyX pointed out, it is always a good idea to use `noremap` respectively `inoremap` if you want to make sure that if `*` or `<c-o>` will be mapped to something else, that this recursive mapping won't be expanded.

Comment: @aminfar: I'm glad I could help ;) I also learned that * searches for the word under the cursor XD That's one thing I like about VIM: You learn a neat new trick every day ;)

Comment: You should use `noremap` and `inoremap`. It will make mapping imune to remapping `*` and `<C-o>`.

Comment: * will move the cursor to the next word. If you want to keep the cursor on the current word try `map <2-LeftMouse> *#`.

Comment: @Yep_It's_Me - that would bring cursor back to start - what would that accomplish ? do not see your point

Comment: @serup it keeps the cursor on the word you click on, instead of moving it to the next occurrence.

Comment: @serup to make it more like an IDE. If I click on a word in IntelliJ, it highlights all occurences of the word, so I can see where the variable is used for instance, but it doesn't move my cursor. It just annoyed me that my cursor was being moved when I clicked something is all.

Comment: @Yep_It's_Me, I use tmux with multiple terminals and one of them is output of TDD - in that window I want the double click to move cursor, but I see what you mean

Answer (score 20):

If you want to highlight the word under the cursor like `*`, but do **not** want to move the cursor then I suggest the following:

```
nnoremap <silent> <2-LeftMouse> :let @/='\V\<'.escape(expand('<cword>'), '\').'\>'<cr>:set hls<cr>
```

Basically this command sets the search register (`@/`) to the current word and turns on `'hlsearch'` so the results are highlighted. By setting `@/` the cursor is not moved as it is with `*` or `#`.

Explanation:

- `<silent>` - to not show the command once executed
- `<2-LeftMouse>` - Double click w/ the left mouse button
- `@/` is the register used for searching with `/` and `?`
- `expand('<cword>')` get the current word under the cursor
- `escape(pattern, '\')` escape the regex in case of meta characters
- `\V` use very-non-magic mode so everything meta character must be escaped with `/`
- `\<` and `\>` to ensure the current word is at a word boundary
- `set hls` set `'hlsearch'` on so highlighting appears

If setting the `@/` register is not your cup of tea than you can use `:match` instead like so:

```
nnoremap <silent> <2-leftMouse> :exe 'highlight DoubleClick ctermbg=green guibg=green<bar>match DoubleClick /\V\<'.escape(expand('<cword>'), '\').'\>/'<cr>
```

To clear the matches just use:

```
:match none
```

Comment: This is one of the most useful lines I have ever had in my .vimrc file. Thank you so much!